# Float Precision and Removing Rounding Errors in Scheme

Tags: floating-point, lisp, scheme, rounding, precision

I have a procedure that returns a float to three decimal places.

```
>(gpa ’(A A+ B+ B))
3.665
```

Is there any way to round this to 3.67 in Scheme?

I'm using [SCM](http://people.csail.mit.edu/jaffer/SCM.html) version 5e7 with Slib 3b3, the additional [Simply Scheme](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~bh/ss-toc2.html) [libraries](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~bh/downloads/simply/) (simply.scm, functions.scm, ttt.scm, match.scm, database.scm) and the answer library I use loaded.

As an aside, I input this into my computer this morning

```
> (* 1 (- 0.5 0.4 0.1))
-27.755575615628913e-18
```

no no no no!

How do you deal with such inaccuracy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
(define (round-off z n)
  (let ((power (expt 10 n)))
    (/ (round (* power z)) power)))

> (round-off 3.665 2)
3.66
> (round-off 3.6677 2)
3.67
```

Note 3.665 rounds to 3.66, not 3.67. (Evens round down; odds round up)

As for your second question.  Use exact numbers:

```
> (* 1 (- #e0.5 #e0.4 #e0.1))
0

> #e0.5
1/2
```

Comment: @[GoZoner](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1286639/gozoner) Nice and clean (mine was kludgy), I like that `(/ (round (* 100 z)) 100)` gets rid of the inaccuracy *and* is a function I can reuse (with whatever power I choose!). Changed `round` to `celing` because it fit what I'm doing. +1. Is `#e` [Racket?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racket_programming_language) SCM (R5RS) threw an error and insisted I use `(* 1 (- (inexact->exact 0.5) (inexact->exact 0.4) (inexact->exact 0.1)))`.

Comment: I've never used Racket.  The `#e` reader syntax might be after R5RS.

Comment: @[GoZoner](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1286639/gozoner) +1 for no Racket. I loathe it to bits (full disclaimer, I'm new to scheme).

Comment: I use R6RS Ikarus.  Larceny (R5RS, R6RS, ERRR5RS) is very good too.  Ikarus is blindingly fast.